# Loop para calcular o maximo valor

Tags: r

Preciso calcular o máximo valor de consumo com base nos valores prévios cada vez que aplico um loop nos dados de consumo. Por exemplo no dia 4, o máximo consumo seria calculado do dia 1 a 4.

Segue o codigo que pensei, mas nao sei como pode ser calculado

```
Maxconsumo<-c()

for (i in 1:length(Consumo)) {
  Maxconsumo <- .........
}

    Dia Consumo
    1   245
    2   256
    3   300
    4   450
    5   245
    6   256
    7   300
    8   450
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Maxconsumo<-c()

Dia = 1:8
Consumo = c(245, 256, 300, 450, 245, 256, 300, 450)
data <- data.frame(Dia, Consumo)

for (i in 1:length(Consumo)) {
  Maxconsumo[i] <- max(data$Consumo[1:i])
}

Maxconsumo
# [1] 245 256 300 450 450 450 450 450
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: De nada! Se foi útil, você pode aceitar e validar a resposta.

Comment: Claro! Desculpe sou novo aqui, como faco para aceitar e validar a sua respostas?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 3):

Se quer uma função semelhante a `cumsum`, mas calculando o máximo acumulado, aqui vai, mas usei um nome diferente do seu para ser consistente com o `R` base.

```
cummax <- function(x){
    x[is.na(x)] <- -Inf
    m <- numeric(length(x))
    m[1] <- x[1]
    for(i in seq_along(x)[-1]){
        m[i] <- if(x[i] > m[i - 1]) x[i] else m[i - 1]
    }
    m
}

cummax(dados$Consumo)
#[1] 245 256 300 450 450 450 450 450
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Dia = 1:8, Consumo = c(245, 256, 300, 450, 245, 
256, 300, 450)), .Names = c("Dia", "Consumo"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIÇÂO.**
Depois de ver a resposta do Willian Vieira editei a minha resposta com uma nova tabela `dados`. Não sei porquê, quando li a tabela do OP não a li bem.